# how to see exact communication in wireshark?

Tags: wireshark, packet-capture, wireshark-dissector

We have installed a proxy inbetween host and internet. when i make a request google.com and if i see the communication in wireshark, i can just see the communication to proxy and reply from proxy, since proxy makes the actual request and reply to host.

in this case, how do we see the actual communication even if proxy is in intermediate. i have tried to open the packet and saw "Follow TCP Stream", but i could not find more information from it.

like communication from host to google.com in wireshark?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. What information are you trying to see that you're not? You've stated you can see packets from host -> proxy, and proxy -> host. Is that not what you're after?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart i see communication from host -> proxy ip address, i don't see , i from proxy -> dest (google.com)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture the traffic between the proxy and the destination, You would need to run wireshark on a machine that can see the traffic between the proxy and the destination. Eg, on the proxy, or on a machine connected to a switch setup to do port mirroring, or ...........

Basically though, without telling us the exact network layout, we cant help.